# sum of as many pairwise distinct positive integers

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum, greedy

Task. The goal of this problem is to represent a given positive integer  as a sum of as many pairwise distinct positive integers as possible. That is, to find the maximum  such that  can be written as 1 + 2 + · · · +  where 1, . . . ,  are positive integers and  ̸=  for a

Sample 1.

Input:

6

Output:

3

1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Using a greedy algorithm which selects the smallest available number is a good approach you chose.

```
n = 17 # The input
x = 0 # The running total
for k in range(1, n): # The maximum number is bounded above by n
    x += k
    if n - x < k + 1: # The next number is too big
        print(k) # Print k
        print(*list(range(1, k)), end=" ") # Print the list of numbers (Except the last)
        print(n - x + k) # Print the last number
        break
```

However, if you only want the number `k` as the output and not the numbers themselves, then you should simply compute triangular numbers and compare those to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools for this.

```
import itertools as it
n=10

for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
    for tup in it.combinations(range(1,n),i):
        if sum(tup) == n:
            print(tup)
            break 
    else:
        continue        
    break
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```